# PolyCenter Netview & Console Manager

Tags: network-monitoring, console-server

I'm looking to replace Polycenter Newview and Polycenter Console Manager with supported products.

I'm starting with this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems).

Do you have any recommendations, either from that list or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Dave,
You may want to take a look at www.netPrefect.com, it is a product designed by the Architect of POLYCENTER Console Manager (Phil Baxter) and will replace both your POLYCENTER Console Manager and NetView installations.  Contact via sales@cyclone-technology.com.

Clair